# Margin and padding reset after jquery effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, effect

I have issue with jquery effect on image hover. Before hovering a few times on image it looks like this:

[image]

After hovering my image stick to the button like this:

[image]

Here's my JS:

```
//For animate images in skills
$('.skills, .contact').find('img').hover(function(){
   $(this).finish().effect("bounce",1000);
}); //End of hover() animate
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row future hideme">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4 col-lg-offset-1">
    <img src="images/angular.png" alt="AngularJS" title="AngularJS">
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#projects"><button name="projects" class="hideme">Check my projects</button></a>
```

CSS:

```
.hideme { opacity: 0; }
.row { margin: 0 0 0 350px; }

  .future {
    margin: 0 0 50px 500px;
  }

  button {
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #D4DFE6;
    padding: 13px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0 0;
  }
```

And here's fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/avm7a6oa/12/

How can I repair this?

Comment: Could you post some html and css? Better if you build a simple demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Edited. I can't find in jsfiddle jqueryUI...

Comment: Thanks for edit. (just to make you know)  jsfiddle.net is a website where you can build demos also you can add jquery or jqueryUi from the javascript options.

Comment: Ok, I find how to add jQueryUI. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is caused by JqueryUI that put `position:absolute;` when you apply a `bounce`. This is resolvable by putting your `img` or the element that will get the bounce inside a `div` with `position:relative;` and the right `height`

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/avm7a6oa/14/).

Comment: I have another question. Now I'm using shake effect. Now my two images stick to each other. I must use width instead of height?

Comment: I don't know relay well jqueryUI effects but i think that it will works.

Answer (score 0):

The bounce animation makes the image be in `absolute` position and so the margin does not affect the other elements anymore.